# Separate resource link Flask Restful API

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am learning Flask Restful API, while following some tutorials I came across an example

```
class Student(Resource):
def get(self):
    return {student data}

def post(self, details):
    return {data stored}

api.add_resource(Student,'/student')
```

here, looking at above example, we can use /student with GET,POST methods to retrieve and store data.
But I would like to have 2 different endpoints for retrieving and storing data, each.
for example

```
/student/get
```

which will call get() function of class Student, to retrieve records of all students, and

```
/student/post
```

which will call post() function of class Student, to store the sent/posted data.

Is it possible to have a single student class but call different methods referred by different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a single `Resource` class but call different methods referred by different endpoints.

**Scenario:**

- We have a `Student` class with `get` and `post` method.
- We can use different route to execute the `get` and `post` method separately or combined.
- E.g.:

  - Endpoint `http://localhost:5000/students/get` can only be used for `get` request of `Student` class.
  - Endpoint `http://localhost:5000/students/post` can only be used for `post` request of `Student` class.
  - Endpoint `http://localhost:5000/students/` can be used for both `get`, and `post` request of `Student` class.

**Solution:**

- To control the different endpoint requests in the resource class, we need to pass some keyword arguments to it.
- We will use `resource_class_kwargs` option of `add_resource` method. Details of `add_resource` can be found in the [official documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.add_resource)
- We will block any unwanted method call using `abort` method. We will return a HTTP status `405` with a response message `Method not allowed` for unwanted method calls in endpoints.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('id', type=int, help='ID of the student')
parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help='Name of the student')



def abort_if_method_not_allowed():
    abort(405, message="Method not allowed")

students = [{"id" : 1, "name": "Shovon"},
            {"id" : 2, "name": "arsho"}]

class Student(Resource):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.get_request_allowed = kwargs.get("get_request_allowed", False)
        self.post_request_allowed = kwargs.get("post_request_allowed", False)
        
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_request_allowed:
            abort_if_method_not_allowed()
        return students

    def post(self):
        if not self.post_request_allowed:
            abort_if_method_not_allowed()
        student_arguments = parser.parse_args()
        student = {'id': student_arguments['id'],
                   'name': student_arguments['name']}
        students.append(student)
        return student, 201


api.add_resource(Student, '/students', endpoint="student",
                 resource_class_kwargs={"get_request_allowed": True, "post_request_allowed": True})
api.add_resource(Student, '/students/get', endpoint="student_get",
                 resource_class_kwargs={"get_request_allowed": True})
api.add_resource(Student, '/students/post', endpoint="student_post",
                 resource_class_kwargs={"post_request_allowed": True})
```

**Expected behaviors:**

- `curl http://localhost:5000/students/get` should call the `get` method of `Student` class.
- `curl http://localhost:5000/students/post -d "id=3" -d "name=Sho" -X POST -v` should call the `post` method of `Student` class.
- `curl http://localhost:5000/students` can call both of the methods of  `Student` class.

**Testing:**

- We will call our enlisted endpoints and test if the behavior is expected for each endpoints.
- Output of `get` request in `students/get`  using `curl http://localhost:5000/students/get`:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Shovon"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "arsho"
        }
    ]
```

- Output of `post` request in `students/post` using `curl http://localhost:5000/students/post -d "id=3" -d "name=Shody" -X POST -v`:

```
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Shody"
    }
```

- Output of get request in `students` using `curl http://localhost:5000/students`:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Shovon"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "arsho"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Shody"
        }
    ]
```

- Output of `post` request in `students` using `curl http://localhost:5000/students -d "id=4" -d "name=Ahmedur" -X POST -v`:

```
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ahmedur"
    }
```

- Output of `post` request in `students/get` using `curl http://localhost:5000/students/get -d "id=5" -d "name=Rahman" -X POST -v`:

```
    {
        "message": "Method not allowed"
    }
```

- Output of `get` request in `students/post` using `curl http://localhost:5000/students/post`:

```
    {
        "message": "Method not allowed"
    }
```

**References:**

- [Official documentation of add_resource method](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.add_resource)